# ansible win exe install 32/64 bit

Tags: windows, automation, ansible, installation, exe

can someone please advise. 
What im doing is downloading phpstorme in remote windows machine and installing it, but it installed 32 bit, how can i force ansible to install 64bit?
Thank you in advance. playbook below.

```
---
- hosts: win
  gather_facts: true
#  ansible_connection: winrm
  tasks:
    name: Download  application
    win_get_url:
      url: https://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-2018.2.5.exe
      dest: 'C:\Users\administrator\Downloads'
    name: Install application
    win_package:
      path: 'C:\Users\administrator\Downloads\PhpStorm-2018.2.5.exe'
      product_id: "PhpStorm"
      arguments: /S /install
      state: present
```

Answer (score 1):

Ansible does not know by itself where to download a 32 bits version or a 64 bits one. If you have 64 bits target machine only, just specify the path of the 64 bits executable.

If you have both architectures, you can write two separate tasks and use the `when` keyword associated with the `ansible_architecture` variable, which value can be `32 bits` or `64 bits`, see below.

Also you probably do not need to have two separates download and install operations, since win_package is able to do both in the same taks.

```
---
- hosts: win
  gather_facts: true
#  ansible_connection: winrm
  tasks:

    name: Download and install application, 32 bit case
    win_package:
      path: 'https://download-cf.jetbrains.com/[path-of-the-32-bits-edition].exe'
      product_id: "PhpStorm"
      arguments: /S /install
      state: present
    when: ansible_architecture == "32 bits"

    name: Download and install application, 64 bit case
    win_package:
      path: 'https://download-cf.jetbrains.com/[path-of-the-64-bits-edition].exe'
      product_id: "PhpStorm"
      arguments: /S /install
      state: present
    when: ansible_architecture == "64 bits"
```

To make it even simplier, you can also use Chocolatey, who provides a phpstorm package, see https://chocolatey.org/packages/phpstorm

Ansible is capable of installing Chocolatey packages, using `win_chocolatey`, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_chocolatey_module.html.

The advantages of using Chocolatey packages are multiple, for instance dependencies management, automatically update version (or stay at specified version if this is wanted), ...

Here your playBook can be reduced to:

```
---
- hosts: win
  gather_facts: true
#  ansible_connection: winrm
  tasks:
    - name: choco install phpstorm
      win_chocolatey:
        name: phpstorm
        state: latest
```